# Why is there mp3 delay present in Swift's AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, mp3, avplayer

So, I'm currently working on an app that plays back recorded audio, but the Swift AVPlayer seems to delay certain parts of the .mp3 massively.

For example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0pwpeVnwQ199Ly4pzTfoIw1dJ5jIsaH/view?usp=sharing

When playing this file through web player, at 1:10:02 I can start to hear voice, but the same voice is not heard through my app until 20 seconds later!

When fiddling around with the file, I noticed that I also noticed some delays when attempting to play the file through QuickTime Player on Mac, but did not see the same delays when opening the file through other browsers or the itunes player.

I'm not really sure what this means, minor skim of google seems to indicate that the itunes player USES the QuickTime player so a delay of 10+ seconds seems insane to me.

Implementation below.

```
class MP3Player {
  private var player: AVPlayer?
  private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
  private var startedPlayingAction: () -> Void = {}
  private var currentURL: URL?
  private var isPlaying: Bool {
    guard let player = player else { return false }

    return player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil
  }

  func pause() {
    self.player?.pause()
  }

  func play(url: URL, offset: Milliseconds, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if url != currentURL {
      self.observer = nil

      let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

      self.player = player

      self.observer = player.observe(\.rate) { player, _ in
        if player.rate > 0 {
          self.startedPlayingAction()
        }
      }
    }

    self.startedPlayingAction = completion
    self.player?.seek(
      to: CMTime(
        seconds: offset / 1000,
        preferredTimescale: player?.currentItem?.currentTime().timescale ?? CMTimeScale(1.0)
      ),
      completionHandler: { _ in
        self.player?.play()
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Using this code, I get multiple points of massive delay with the most noticeable delay at around 1:10:02. Can anyone explain why this delay exists? And why on earth QuickTime Player would also have this delay but other players wouldn't?